# Get value of the data member using overloaded assignment operator or overloaded left shift operator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload assignment operator and left shift operator to make it return the data stored in the class. I'm trying to make overload assignment operator and left shift operator as convivence operators for accessing data inside the class.
I've been able to overload assignment operator to set data but for get data I'm getting the bellow error.

Error in tempate.h

```
error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters
error C2805: binary 'operator =' has too few parameters
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters
error C2805: binary 'operator =' has too few parameters
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Error in main.cpp

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'SetOnce<int>' to 'int'
```

Error Code

```
template<typename T>
inline T SetOnce<T>::operator<<(void) const
{
    return this->get();
}

template<typename T>
inline T SetOnce<T>::operator=(void) const
{
    return this->get();
}
```

Complete Code:

template.h

```
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

class DataNotSetException: public std::exception
{
public:
    static inline const char* message = "Data Not Set before Get Operation";
    const char* what()
    {
        return message;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class SetOnce
{
private:
    T data;
    std::once_flag flag;
    std::atomic_bool data_set{ false };
    void do_once(const T& data);
public:
    T get(void) const;
    void set(const T& data);
    bool is_set(void) const;
    void operator=(const T& data);
    T operator<< (void) const; //Error in this line
    T operator= (void) const; //Error in this line
    SetOnce() {}
};

template<typename T>
inline void SetOnce<T>::do_once(const T& data)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->data_set.store(true);
}

//If data is not been set throw data not set exception (DataNotSetException)
template<typename T>
inline T SetOnce<T>::get(void) const
{
    if (this->is_set() == true)
    {
        return this->data;
    }
    else
    {
        throw DataNotSetException();
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void SetOnce<T>::set(const T& data)
{
    std::call_once(this->flag, &SetOnce::do_once, this, data);
}

template<typename T>
inline bool SetOnce<T>::is_set(void) const
{
    return this->data_set.load();
}

template<typename T>
inline void SetOnce<T>::operator=(const T& data)
{
    this->set(data);
}

template<typename T>
inline T SetOnce<T>::operator<<(void) const //Error in this line
{
    return this->get();
}

template<typename T>
inline T SetOnce<T>::operator=(void) const //Error in this line
{
    return this->get();
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(void)
{
    SetOnce<int> a1;
    a1 = 175;
    std::cout << a1.get() << std::endl;
    int z1 = a1; //Error in this line
    std::cout << z1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Operators may be overloaded but it's not allowed to change their arity (i.e. how many parameters have to be there). Hence, shift operator and assignment operator have to be binary operators. (This is in other words what the compiler is telling you precisely in its first two error messages.)

Comment: You cannot do this. Those operators must have two arguments,

Comment: Could you give an example how you want to use those two operators? = and  << (by the looks of them) seem to be more suited for setting a value. Without parameters you would just try to read and  return a value.

Comment: @Sebastian I've given one example in the main function whereby I assign `int z1 = a1;` and on similar grounds I was thinking about `int z1 << a1;`.

Comment: But then your function needs to receive the `a1` as parameter. The copy assignment operator needs as single parameter either the `SetOnce<T>` type as value, as reference or as const reference. The leftshift has either two parameters, if it is a (possibly friend) free function, or one parameter, if it is a member function.

Comment: `operator <<` is a **binary** operator, it needs **two** arguments

Comment: @Raildex depending on whether it is a free function or a member function.

Comment: @Sebastian I guess "argument" is the wrong word for it.
whether its a binary operator or not doesn't depend on that.
a<<b is just syntax for a.operator<<(b) or operator<<(a,b). operator << needs two operands.

Comment: The operators have two operands, the member functions have one implicit parameter (the object itself) and one explicit parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is two in fact: 1. Operator Overloading; 2. Cast Operator

## Operator Overloading

To overload operators, you should understand what [function overloading and operator overloading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) are. And your overloading should meet some basic function overloading requirements, such as an operator's [function signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature#:%7E:text=A%20function%20signature%20consists%20of,the%20compilers%20to%20the%20linkers.).

For example, `operator=` and `operator<<` are binary operators, which means you should provide two and only two parameters to them. Besides, `operator=` usually returns a reference to the object, and `operator<<` usually returns a reference to an `std::ostream` object.

The corrected operator overloading functions are as follows:

```cpp
// in class SetOnce's declaration
SetOnce<T> &operator=(const T &other);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SetOnce<T>& obj);

// outside the class's declaration
template <typename T> inline SetOnce<T> &SetOnce<T>::operator=(const T &other) {
  // if data has been set, ignore the assignment
  if (!this->data_set) {
    this->set(other);
    this->data_set = true;
  }
  return *this;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const SetOnce<T> &obj) {
  os << obj.data;
  return os;
}
```

Here I provided two kinds of overloading.

1. Function `SetOnce<T> &SetOnce<T>::operator=(const T &other)` is overloaded as a member function. The reason why we only provided one parameter to a binary operator is because `this` is implicitly used as a parameter to the first function, which means we don't have to write it out explicitly.
2. Function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SetOnce<T>& obj)` is not `SetOnce`'s member function, which is called [*friend function*](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/friend-functions-in-cpp/#:%7E:text=A%20friend%20function%20in%20C%2B%2B%20is%20a%20function%20that%20is,class%20functions%20or%20function%20templates.). No `this` is implicitly provided, so we provided two parameters. Overloading with friend function will break encapsulation, which deserve considerate twice. A better way to do this is to overload `operator<<` outside the class and don't mark this function as `friend`, then use `SetOnce::get` in the function.

`operator<<` is usually used to print, I don't recommend you to use it to assign value. But you can still use it to do so, as long as your function's signature meets the requirements. A possible function signature is `SetOnce<T>& operator<<(const T& val)` and a possible way to use it may be:

```cpp
SetOnce<int> s;
int a = 5;
s << a;
```

## Cast Operator

In you `main` function, there is one script:

```cpp
int z1 = a1; // Assign an object of SetOnce<int> to int
```

This requires [cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cast-operator-parens?view=msvc-170) to handle the job.

Thus, you should implement this function in your `SetOnce`:

```cpp
explicit operator int() const {return this->get();}
```

## Code

template.h:

```cpp
// template.h
#pragma once
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class DataNotSetException : public std::exception {
public:
  static inline const char *message = "Data Not Set before Get Operation";
  const char *what() { return message; }
};

template <typename T> class SetOnce {
private:
  T data;
  std::once_flag flag;
  std::atomic_bool data_set{false};
  void do_once(const T &data);

public:
  T get(void) const;
  void set(const T &data);
  bool is_set(void) const;
  // T operator<<(void) const; // Error in this line
  // T operator=(void) const;  // Error in this line
  SetOnce<T> &operator=(const T &other);
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SetOnce<T>& obj);
  explicit operator int() const {return this->get();}

  SetOnce() {}
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const SetOnce<T> &obj) {
  os << obj.data;
  return os;
}

template <typename T> inline void SetOnce<T>::do_once(const T &data) {
  this->data = data;
  this->data_set.store(true);
}

// If data is not been set throw data not set exception (DataNotSetException)
template <typename T> inline T SetOnce<T>::get(void) const {
  if (this->is_set() == true) {
    return this->data;
  } else {
    throw DataNotSetException();
  }
}

template <typename T> inline void SetOnce<T>::set(const T &data) {
  std::call_once(this->flag, &SetOnce::do_once, this, data);
}

template <typename T> inline bool SetOnce<T>::is_set(void) const {
  return this->data_set.load();
}

template <typename T> inline SetOnce<T> &SetOnce<T>::operator=(const T &other) {
  // if data has been set, ignore the assignment
  if (!this->data_set) {
    this->set(other);
    this->data_set = true;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include "template.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  SetOnce<int> a1;
  a1 = 175;
  std::cout << a1.get() << std::endl;
  int z1 = (int)a1;
  std::cout << z1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: With in class and outside the class you probably mean in and outside the 'class declaration'?

Comment: @Sebastian Yeah, I'm not a native English speaker, could you tell me the right way to say it?

Comment: Me neither. I am recommending to replace 'class' with 'class declaration' in those comments. The class declaration is the `class { }` block, typically within the header file. I think that is what you meant.